# Refer to common values within an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object with nested objects that have the same variables within those nested objects properties. I'm trying to make my code more DRY by consolidating the common variables into a property of that nested object, but I'm not sure if this is correct or the best way to write it. Anybody have any thoughts?

**Usage**

I'm calling the various functions as callbacks for jQuery each/onclick statements.

```
$('#foo').each(foo.part1.begin);
$('.bar a').on('click', foo.part1.middle);
```

In the case where I'm using `.each`, I'm appending data attributes for tracking in an analytics tool i.e. when a user clicks a link, it is sent with those attributes. In the case where I'm binding to an event, I'm sending the a special analytics tag for a custom event.

I've updated the first property `begin` in the `foo` object to illustrate what I'm doing. I have a utilities library with a function that takes `$this` and an object, the function loops through the object and sets all of the atttributes on the anchor tag, etc.

**Current Implementation:**

```
var foo = {
    part1: {
        begin: function () {
            var $this = jQuery(this),
                name = 'the beginning of time',
                color = 'blue',
                type = 'blackberries';

            utility.loopThroughAndSetAttributes($this, {
                name: name,
                color: color,
                type: type
            });
        },

        middle: function () {
            var name = 'the beginning of time',
                color = 'blue',
                type = 'strawberries';

            console.log(name + color + type);
        },

        end: function () {
            var name = 'the beginning of time',
                color = 'blue',
                type = 'raspberries';

            console.log(name + color + type);
        }
    },
    part2: {
        begin: function () {
            var name = 'the middle of the city',
                color = 'green',
                type = 'pluto';

            console.log(name + color + type);
        },

        middle: function () {
            var name = 'the middle of the city',
                color = 'green',
                type = 'mars';

            console.log(name + color + type);
        },

        end: function () {
            var name = 'the middle of the city',
                color = 'green',
                type = 'earth';

            console.log(name + color + type);
        },
    }
};
```

**Proposed Solution:** create a new property of the nested object and refer to that property within the function.

```
var foo = {
    part1: {

        name: 'the beginning of time',
        color: 'blue',

        begin: function () {
            var name = foo.part1.name,
                color = foo.part1.color,
                type = 'blackberries';

            console.log(name + color + type);
        },

        middle: function () {
            var name = foo.part1.name,
                color = foo.part1.color,
                type = 'strawberries';

            console.log(name + color + type);
        },

        end: function () {
            var name = foo.part1.name,
                color = foo.part1.color,
                type = 'raspberries';

            console.log(name + color + type);
        }
    },
    part2: {

        name: 'the middle of the city',
        color: 'green',

        begin: function () {
            var name = foo.part1.name,
                color = foo.part1.color,
                type = 'pluto';

            console.log(name + color + type);
        },

        middle: function () {
            var name = foo.part1.name,
                color = foo.part1.color,
                type = 'mars';

            console.log(name + color + type);
        },

        end: function () {
            var name = foo.part1.name,
                color = foo.part1.color,
                type = 'earth';

            console.log(name + color + type);
        },
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you show a little of how you use this? I think we can greatly reduce the amount of code here, depending on its usage.

Comment: @Cory, you bet. Let me edit now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword:

```
part1: {
   name: 'the beginning of time',
   color: 'blue',
   begin: function () {
       var name = this.name,
       // ...         
   },
```

Also you can create a constructor function and avoid duplicating code snippets.

```
var Foo = function(params) {
   this.name = params.name;
   this.color = params.color;
   // ...
}

Foo.prototype.begin = function() {
    // this.name...
};

var foo = {};
foo.part1 = new Foo({
    name: 'the beginning of time',
    color: 'red'
});

foo.part2 = new Foo({
   name: 'bar',
   color: 'baz'
});
```

**Edit**: I'm not really sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but there are some points that can be relevant.

jQuery `on` method sets the `this` value of the passed function to the clicked element. For overwriting the `this` value to refer to the instance you can use the `Function.prototype.bind` or jQuery `$.proxy` method:

```
$('.bar a').on('click', foo.part1.middle.bind(foo.part1));

Foo.prototype.middle = function(event) {
    var clickedElement  = event.currentTarget;
    // `this` here refers to the instance
};
```

Another option is attaching the instance to element using jQuery `.data()` method:

```
$('element').data('foo', foo.part1);
```

Then for getting the data you can use the `data` method as a getter:

```
var foo = $('element').data('foo');
```

And when it comes to analytics using D3 library is recommended!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like most of the functionality lives within a "part", so let's create a function object that encapsulates that functionality:

```
function Part(name, color, types) {
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.types = types;
    this.begin = function() {
        console.log(this.name + this.color + this.types.begin);  
    };
    this.middle = function() {
        console.log(this.name + this.color + this.types.middle);  
    };
    this.end = function() {
        console.log(this.name + this.color + this.types.end);  
    };
}
```

Now you can construct your `foo`, with common functionality removed except for the definition of the parts the parameters each needs:

```
var foo = {
    part1: new Part('the beginning of time', 'blue', 
        { begin: 'blackberries', middle: 'strawberries', end: 'raspberries' }),
    part2: new Part('the middle of the city', 'green', 
        { begin: 'pluto', middle: 'mars', end: 'earth'})
};
```

And the usage here would be:

```
foo.part1.begin();
foo.part1.middle();
foo.part1.end();

foo.part2.begin();
foo.part2.middle();
foo.part2.end();
```

You could take this further, but I'll leave it at this for now.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use function factories for these sorts of "almost the same" functions.

```
function fooFunc(name, color, type) {
  return function() {
    console.log(name + color + type);
  };
}

var foo = {
  part1: {
    begin: fooFunc('the beginning of time', 'blue', 'blackberries'),
    middle: fooFunc('the beginning of time', 'blue', 'strawberries'), 
    end: fooFunc('the beginning of time', 'blue', 'raspberries')
  },
  part2: {
    begin: fooFunc('the middle of the city', 'green', 'pluto'),
    middle: fooFunc('the middle of the city', 'green', 'mars'), 
    end: fooFunc('the middle of the city', 'green', 'earth')
  }
};
```